# How do I filter a matrix in R by matching another array

Tags: r

now I have a matrix in R:

```
a=matrix(c("A","B","B","C",61,25,23,28,43,74,67,11),nrow=4)
```

and another array

```
b=c("B","C","D").
```

How can I filter the matrix a so it returns just the matches i.e.,

```
matrix(c("B","B","C",25,23,28,74,67,11),nrow=3)
```

I've tried to match them one by one but it's really time-consuming since I have a big dataset.

Thank you! -Natalia

Comment: You are looking for the `%in%` operator. Try `a[a[,1] %in% b,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `%in%` operator:

```
a[a[,1] %in% b,]
```

Comment: a[a[,1] %in% b,] would be shorter